# Embedding Gmail compose window in HTML

Tags: html, iframe, gmail, google-workspace

I am working on a website where I want to `embed a Gmail compose window`. This is a corporate page with Google Workspace being a standard in the company so the user has its own account and opening gmail makes it automatically log in to the corporate account. But when I embed this:

```
<iframe src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?view=cm&fs=1&to=TO&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY"
 width="1000" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I get the information in the iframe that mail.google.com refused to connect.

[image]

In general, what I want to achieve is to allow easy way of sending emails for the OTRS that the user can send directly from the page with his/her email recorded (that's why I want to make sure that it's sent from the gmail account from a specific user that has its own email in the company domain and not via some standard Contact Form i.e.  Contact Form 7).

Is there any solution to make it work?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the error.   I really don think google is going to let you run in an iframe.

Comment: @DaImTo - I added the iframe I get. I know this may be security reasons, but it's possible to embed other elements of Google Workspace such as Forms, Sheets or Drive Folders so I want to be sure this is impossible to be done with Gmail.